# DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "failed to get message for Windows Error 126"

Tags: oracle, cx-oracle, dbt, dagster

I am working with dagster and dbt. I have a test repo that I use both on a Debian VM and on my Windows PC. On Debian everything works fine, here on Windows I receive the following Oracle error and can't fix it.

```
ERROR  oracle adapter: Got an error when attempting to open an Oracle connection:
'DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library:
"failed to get message for Windows Error 126".
See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help'

INFO  oracle adapter: Rolling back transaction.
```

I am receiving this error even after:

- Downloading Oracle Instant client and unzipping it in my Oracle folder *(C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\instantclient_21_6)*
- Setting the ORACLE_HOME and PATH.
- Installing and importing cx_Oracle.
- Initializing cx_Oracle.

Comment: You could make use of the new driver python-oracledb thin mode -- which doesn't require any Oracle Instant Client: https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/

Comment: The error suggests some sort of installation issue -- but I don't know enough about Windows to be able to give useful advice!